# How to end a looping coroutine in Lua?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm currently working on a game using Roblox (which uses Lua).  It is a basically made up of several minigames.  At the beginning of each round, all the players in game are put in a table and teleported to an area.  That is where the coroutine comes into play.  As the round is in progress, I want a coroutine to start.  Every second that coroutine checks if the player's health is below zero, and removes them from the currentPlayer table if it is.

Sorry if I am not describing the problem correctly, but the coroutine will not yield.  I haven't used coroutines before, so I am probably trying to yield it the wrong way.  I know most of you will not be familiar with Roblox, but the Lua syntax is the same.

Can someone please give me an example of how I would end a looping coroutine?

```
currentPlayers = {}
roundTime = 60

local lookForWinners = coroutine.create(function()
  while coroutine.running do
    wait(1)
    for i, v in pairs(currentPlayers) do
      if v.Character.Humanoid.Health <= 0 then
        table.remove(currentPlayers, v)
      end
    end
  end
end)


while wait() do
  repeat display("Two or more players need to be in the game.", 1) until #_G.plrs > 1 --Ignore, just checks if two+ players are in game.
  display("Picking a map...", 3) pickMap()
  teleport(0, 500, 0)
  coroutine.resume(lookForWinners)
  wait(roundTime)
  print("Round over")
  coroutine.yield(lookForWinners)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the code, my bad for not posting it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Lua is a single-threaded language. Coroutines do not cause functions to execute in parallel.

Coroutines are effectively just a way to make a function that can pause its own execution (using `coroutine.yield`), that can be resumed from outside (using `coroutine.resume`). [There is no "coroutine.running"](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.6): there's only one line "running" at any given time.

If Roblox were meant for you to use `wait()` to jump out of the Lua thread, you would write this as a series of loops that check their condition and then call `wait()`:

```
local currentPlayers={}
local roundTime = 60

while #_G.plrs > 1 do
  display("Two or more players need to be in the game.", 1)
  wait()
end
display("Picking a map...", 3) pickMap()
teleport(0, 500, 0)

for i=0, roundTime do
  for i, v in pairs(currentPlayers) do
    if v.Character.Humanoid.Health <= 0 then
      table.remove(currentPlayers, v)
    end
  end
  wait(1)
end
print("Round over")
```

However, **this is bad code**. (Whenever you write code, let loops with a "wait" function in them serve to indicate that something is being done incorrectly.) You should be using Roblox's [Events](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Category%3aEvents) to handle your game's logic.

- Check to see if the game should start only when the number of players changes.
- "Look For Winners" only when a Humanoid's health changes (the HealthChanged event).
- Run the timer on some kind of timer or interval (don't forget that you'll probably want to end your game early once somebody has won).

Events have *many, many* advantages over a busy loop; the most visible one will be that your checks occur *when* the thing they're checking for happens, and not later.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you follow Stuart's advice to use events; this is mostly to provide additional information on what coroutines are to help you use them correctly.

Think of coroutines as functions that may return values, but with a twist: while a "normal" function completes when it executes `return`, when you `yield` from a coroutine, it saves its state, so that `resume` can then continue from the point where you yielded as if nothing happened. Note that you only `yield` *from* a coroutine and only to the point where the `resume` of that coroutine was done (this is no different from calling a function and returning from it; the control returns to the point where you called the function).

In addition to that, `resume` and `yield` calls allow you to pass values to the coroutine and return (intermediate) values from the coroutine. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424445/lua-lua-resume-and-lua-yield-argument-purposes/13424662#13424662) for an example of how this can be used.

One can still `return` from a coroutine and it's no different from returning from a function, which completes its execution. If you check the status of the coroutine at that time (`coroutine.status`), it should be "dead".

So, to answer your question how you can end a looping coroutine: you can `return` from it, you can `yield()` from it (and never `resume` it again), or you can call `error()`, which you can then catch and check for in the result of the `resume` call. Having said that, I agree with Stuart that it may be the wrong way to solve your problem.